# Adding two 2D NumPy arrays ignoring NaNs in them

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, nan

What is the right way to add 2 numpy arrays a and b (both 2D) with numpy.nan as missing value?

1. `a + b`

or

2. `numpy.ma.sum(a,b)`

Comment: What does "missing value" signify in adding?

Comment: thanks @Divakar, the missing value should be ignored. Not sure what numpy does if one array has a missing value and the other does not.

Comment: @user308827 Have you tried it?

Comment: I have, a + b seems to be working in one case. However, in another case, it ends up in all values being nan

Comment: Please provide sample input and expected output. It's unclear what you are asking.

Comment: Also, what does "the right way" mean? For now it seems terribly unclear and opinion-based.

Answer (score 15):

Since the inputs are 2D arrays, you can stack them along the third axis with [`np.dstack`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dstack.html) and then use [`np.nansum`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nansum.html) which would ensure `NaNs` are ignored, unless there are `NaNs` in both input arrays, in which case output would also have `NaN`. Thus, the implementation would look something like this -

```
np.nansum(np.dstack((A,B)),2)
```

Sample run -

```
In [157]: A
Out[157]: 
array([[ 0.77552455,  0.89241629,         nan,  0.61187474],
       [ 0.62777982,  0.80245533,         nan,  0.66320306],
       [ 0.41578442,  0.26144272,  0.90260667,         nan],
       [ 0.65122428,  0.3211213 ,  0.81634856,         nan],
       [ 0.52957704,  0.73460363,  0.16484994,  0.20701344]])

In [158]: B
Out[158]: 
array([[ 0.55809925,  0.1339353 ,         nan,  0.35154039],
       [ 0.94484722,  0.23814073,  0.36048809,  0.20412318],
       [ 0.25191484,         nan,  0.43721322,  0.95810905],
       [ 0.69115038,  0.51490958,         nan,  0.44613473],
       [ 0.01709308,  0.81771896,  0.3229837 ,  0.64013882]])

In [159]: np.nansum(np.dstack((A,B)),2)
Out[159]: 
array([[ 1.3336238 ,  1.02635159,         nan,  0.96341512],
       [ 1.57262704,  1.04059606,  0.36048809,  0.86732624],
       [ 0.66769925,  0.26144272,  1.33981989,  0.95810905],
       [ 1.34237466,  0.83603089,  0.81634856,  0.44613473],
       [ 0.54667013,  1.55232259,  0.48783363,  0.84715226]])
```

Comment: The behavior that `NaN` is returned when both inputs are `NaN` changed for NumPy version >1.9.0. In the newer versions, zero is returned!

Answer (score 6):

Just replace the `NaN`s with zeros in both arrays:

```
a[np.isnan(a)] = 0  # replace all nan in a with 0
b[np.isnan(b)] = 0  # replace all nan in b with 0
```

And then perform the addition:

```
a + b
```

This relies on the fact that `0` is the ["identity element"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_element) for addition.