# How to replicate excel sumproduct function correctly in python?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe like below which I need to calculate the weight average. In excel, if I use sumproduct function, I will get a result of 15.25. However, when I use the following code, it gives me 0. How to correct this in the code?
[image]

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = { 'product1':['N/A'],
  'product2':[15.25],
  'p1 weight':[0],
  'p2 weight':[4]}

df1=pd.DataFrame(df1)
df1.fillna(0,inplace=True)


cols_left = [c for c in df1.columns if 'product' in c]
cols_right = [c for c in df1.columns if 'weight' in c]

result = (df1[cols_left] * df1[cols_right]).sum(axis=1) / df1[cols_right].sum(axis=1)
df1['result'] = result
```

results as below

[image]

Be noted, I have to use the cols_left and cols_right approach, because in my real work situation, I have +100 columns which need to be performed the weight average calculation based on the corresponding columns.

Instead of doing hard coding like `df1['result1'] = (df1['product1'] * df1['p1 weight'] + df1['product2'] * df1['p2 weight'] )/ df1['p1 weight'] + df1['p2 weight']` and so on, I group all the corresponding columns in the cols_left and cols_right respectively before the sum product calculation.

Any advice are greatly appreciated.

Comment: There are a few ways to do this using numpy as well as pandas. Numpy would be cleaner but if you want a purely pandas solution you might have to write a bit more code. Check my answer below for examples of both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas supports (and enforces) data alignment. When you apply an operation to two data frames, the operation is applied to the rows and columns with the same index (name), not at the same position. To apply operations to a pair of columns with different names, you should extract the underlying numpy arrays from them:

```
# Clean the NAs
import numpy as np
df1.replace("N/A", np.nan, inplace=True)

(df1[cols_left].fillna(0).values * df1[cols_right].values).sum() / df1[cols_right].sum(1)
#0    15.25
```

Note that `nan * 0` is still a `nan`. You must convert `nan`s to finite numbers (e.g., to 0s) to obtain a numeric result.

Comment: Thanks DYZ, but does this code works? I ran it but it gave me error..

Comment: I assumed that you had `nan` in the first column, not an `"N/A"`. Fixed it for you.

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly. I try to figure out how your solution differs from my original code. It seems to me you have added .values after the cols_left and cols_right, as well as replace N/A with np.nan follow by fillna with 0. I try to understand how this make a difference. But thanks a lot for your solution. It's awesome.

Comment: Correct, `.values` is the key.

Comment: Thanks. Do you mind to explain if .values "apply operations to a pair of columns with different names" like you mentioned in the earlier comment?

Comment: `.values` is a reference to the original numpy array. Numpy columns do not have names, they only have indexes. When you multiply two numpy arrays, the first column of the first array is multiplied by the first column of the other array. When you multiply two pandas dataframes, column A of the first dataframe is multiplied by column A of the second dataframe, regardless of their locations.

Comment: Thanks DYZ. Really appreciated for your helps.

Answer (score 2):

## Numpy method:

> df1 for below examples is defined in the last section of my answer

The numpy way of solving this would be to take a `np.nanprod` followed by a `.sum()`. This answer is inspired from [this StackOverflow solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33269803/4755954).

```
A = df1.iloc[:,:2].values
B = df1.iloc[:,2:].values

num = np.nanprod(np.dstack((A,B)),2).sum(1)
den = df1.iloc[:,2:].sum(1)

df1['sumproduct'] = num/den
print(df1)
```

```
   product1  product2  p1 weight  p2 weight  sumproduct
0       NaN     15.25          0          4       15.25
1      10.0     10.00          2          3       10.00
2       8.0      2.00          5          1        7.00
```

## Pandas method:

Pandas' way can be a bit complex since the `pandas.DataFrame.dot` (which is basically the sumproduct you want) doesn't give you a lot of flexibility with dataframes with different column names. However, you can use `pandas.groupby` with a custom grouper to do the product easily.

Try this approach which is inspired by [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58435789/4755954) -

```
num_base_cols = 2 #number of columns per group
num_repeat = 2 #number of such groups

col_groups = np.tile(np.arange(num_base_cols), num_repeat) #[0,1,0,1] grouper

num = df1.groupby(col_groups, axis=1).prod().sum(1)
den = df1.iloc[:,2:].sum(1)

df1['sumproduct'] = num/den
print(df1)
```

```
   product1  product2  p1 weight  p2 weight  sumproduct
0       NaN     15.25          0          4       15.25
1      10.0     10.00          2          3       10.00
2       8.0      2.00          5          1        7.00
```

---

**PS** - I use this dataframe with some added rows to demonstrate above solutions. Also, I use proper `np.nan` instead of `NAN` strings for realistic dummy inputs.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np   #for adding proper Nans instead of strings

## added a few more rows for testing ##
#######################################
df1 = { 'product1':[np.nan,10,8],
        'product2':[15.25,10,2],
        'p1 weight':[0,2,5],
        'p2 weight':[4,3,1]}

df1=pd.DataFrame(df1)
#######################################
```

Comment: Thanks Akshy Sehgal a lot for offering a solution in both pandas and numpy. I saw that stackoverflow answer but wasn't sure how to apply that method into my code, so thanks a lot for this demonstration. The issue is I don't always have 2 columns per group, sometime it's 1, or 3, or 4 or even different numbers per group, but number of groups should be fixed, which is always 2 (product and weight). If I use this approach, I would need to think how to make it dynamic instead of hard coding the number of columns per group.

Comment: You can choose the right number of columns and group sizes to create a grouper. For your example you need a [0,1,0,1] grouper.. where the columns with 0 get a `prod()` and columns with 1 get a `prod()`. If you have more groups (say 4 groups), you need to have a grouper which looks like [0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3] which would behave accordingly. Just change `num_base_cols = 4` for that.

Comment: Thanks Akshay. This approach is a bit advance for me, do you mind to show me a quick demonstration? Either way, really appreciated for your helps.